# I can't send my newly sorted array to FlatList. How can I send it correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pulling my data(user.notes) from Firebase `datastore`. `user` is a doc, and `notes` is an array that stores `objects(maps)` in it.

And those objects have their `createdAt` time values like:

user = [..., {title: 'First', details: 'first one', time: '1677959929938'}, ...]

Since the 'user' variable is a *State*, I assign it to a normal array 'arr' to change its order with `sort()` function. I want to sort them whenever I call `changeOrder()` function. It is working when I choose the cases, it logs the right outputs. But I cannot transfer my newly sorted 'arr' array to the FlatList.

It actually flashes the right order (time ascending) for a second, but it quickly turns back to normal order. It shows the *time descending* order correctly, but it is original order anyway.

**My Component:**

```
const Notes = ({navigation}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
    
    let arr = user.notes;

    function changeOrder(o) {
      setValue(o);
      arr = user.notes;
      switch (value) {
        case 'titleA':
          console.log('titleA');
          break;
        case 'titleD':
          console.log('titleD');
          break;
        case 'timeA':
          arr.sort((a,b)=> a.time - b.time);
          console.log('Artan: ', arr);
          break;
        case 'timeD':
          arr.sort((a,b)=> b.time - a.time);
          console.log('Azalan: ', arr);
          break;
  
        default:
          console.log('empty');
      }
    }

    const q = query(collUser, where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email))

    useEffect(()=>{
      const subscriber = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          setUser({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        });
        
        setLoading(false);
      });
      return () => subscriber();
    },[user])
    
    if (loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} size="large" color="#0000ff" />;
    }

    function addHandler () {
      navigation.navigate('AddNote', {docId: user.id, notes: user.notes});
    }

    function renderTile({item}) {
        function pressHandler() {navigation.navigate("ViewNote", {noteId: item.id, t: item.title, d: item.details, time: item.createdAt});}
        // console.log(item.title);
        return <NoteTile 
                title={item.title}
                det={item.details}
                pressFunc={pressHandler} />;
    }

  return (
      <View style={styles.flatlistContainer}>

        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome</Text>
          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            <Picker changeOrder={changeOrder} />
          </View>
        </View>

        <FlatList data={arr}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.time}
          renderItem={renderTile}
          numColumns={2}
          style={styles.flatlist} />
        
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Pressable android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={addHandler}>
            <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name='add' size={40}/>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
  )
}

export default Notes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of main issues I can see in the code provided.

Firstly, the `user` state is not being updated with the sorted array within your `changeOrder()` function. I would personally get rid of the `let arr = user.notes` altogether. A better way of doing this would be to make a clone of the `user.notes` and then using `setUser` to update the state within the `changeOrder()` function. Like so.

```
function changeOrder(o) {
  setValue(o);
  const sortedArr = [...user.notes]; // make a clone of the original array
  switch (value) {
    case 'titleA':
      console.log('titleA');
      break;
    case 'titleD':
      console.log('titleD');
      break;
    case 'timeA':
      sortedArr.sort((a,b)=> a.time - b.time);
      console.log('Artan: ', sortedArr);
      break;
    case 'timeD':
      sortedArr.sort((a,b)=> b.time - a.time);
      console.log('Azalan: ', sortedArr);
      break;

    default:
      console.log('empty');
  }
  setUser({...user, notes: sortedArr});
}
```

This `setUser` will take all the previous `user` state and update the `notes` property within that state with the `sortedArr`.

Secondly, you want the `FlatList` to be reactive, so here you can use `user.notes` directly within the `FlatList`, because this is already in state and when that state changes via the `changeOrder()` function it will cause a re-render and reflect the updated order.

```
<FlatList data={user.notes}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.time}
  renderItem={renderTile}
  numColumns={2}
  style={styles.flatlist} />
```

This will hopefully give you a few pointers as to why its not working.

Comment: Those are very helpful guidance. Thank you for your help and effort.